# Does notify_one() inside locked scope prevent race condition?

Tags: c++, race-condition

I have a wrapper class that handles calling a synchronouse operation between one thread that calls the operation and another thread that process (executes) the synchronouse operation. The caller thread is refered to as the *Requiring side* and the processing thread is refered to as the *Providing side*.

```
    template <class tBridgeDeclType>
    class LockableOperationT : public OperationSignatureT<tBridgeDeclType>
        {
        public:
            explicit LockableOperationT(const OperationSignatureT<tBridgeDeclType> &fOperation) :
                mOperation(fOperation) { }
            virtual ~LockableOperationT() { }


            void waitUntilProcessed()
                {

                // Lock the bridge from the requiring side.
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> processLock(mMutex);

                // Wait until operation has been processed and take care of spurious wake ups.
                mConditionVariable.wait(processLock, [this]{ return(mHasBeenProcessed); });
                }


            void process(void) override final
                {

                // Process operation. Have to remove const to do this
                const_cast<OperationSignatureT<tBridgeDeclType> &>(mOperation).process();

                    // Lock the bridge from the providing side.
                    {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> processLock(mMutex);
                    mHasBeenProcessed = true;
                    }

                // Requiring side is notified that the operation has been processed
                mConditionVariable.notify_one();
                }


        // Members
        protected:
            const OperationSignatureT<tBridgeDeclType> &mOperation;
            bool mHasBeenProcessed = false;
            std::mutex mMutex;
            std::condition_variable mConditionVariable;
        };
```

The sequence is that the caller (requirer) sends the operation to the executor (provider) and waits for the operation to be synchronously completed. The executor receives the operation, executes it and notifies the caller that it has been done. The caller then deletes the operation. The caller deleting the LockableOperationT<> object after returning from waitUntilProcessed() fits very nicely with the RAII (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) idiom.

In the code above there is a race condition concerning the line

```
mConditionVariable.notify_one();
```

The race condition is as follows:

Thread-1

```
Issues a call to waitUntilProcessed()
Locks & waits for mHasBeenProcessed == true
```

Thread-2 - process()

```
sets HasBeenprocedded = true
exits locked scope (has still not finished the process()-method)
```

Thread-1 - waitUntilProcessed()

```
Spurious wake up
Finds mHasBeenProcessed == true
Returns
Thread-1-Caller deletes LockableOperationT<>.
```

Thread-2 - process()

```
Calls mConditionVariable.notify_one() for the now deleted LockableOperationT<>
```

My question is if the race condition would be avioded by moving the notification inside the locked scope, i.e.

```
    // Lock the bridge from the providing side.
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> processLock(mMutex);
    mHasBeenProcessed = true;

    // Requiring side is notified that the operation has been processed
    mConditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
```

or would it only move the race to some other place?

/Nils

Comment: Looks ok on the first glance.

Comment: you may want to protect your condition variables against spurious wakeup, have another atomic bool that you check on wakeup in a loop, the condition variable may wake up the thread randomly on some systems.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks for your feedback. The condition actually is protected against spurios wake-up by the use of the wait predicate ([this]{ return(mHasBeenProcessed);). It is the notification that gets lost.

Comment: yes you are correct, the other optimal solution would be to move the condition variable to some globally allocated memory pool and have a `pmr::shared_ptr` to it on the stack, but that has slightly higher overhead.

Comment: I agree that a `shared_ptr` would also work. However, I'm not sure that has a higher overhead. The thing with notifying inside the critical section is that the awoken thread tries to acquire the mutex that is still taken. I've seen it cause additional system calls in practise. You can do a lot of memory allocation/deallocation for the price of one system call. So I think this needs benchmarking